How to Ensure Consistent Spacing Before Each Paragraph in a Word Document Using Python?
I am trying to generate a Word document where each word is on a separate page and has a specific amount of spacing before the paragraph. I am using the python-docx library to create the Word document. However, I noticed that the same spacing before each word is not consistently applied.
Here is a snippet of my code:
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
import os

def create_word_document(words, output_path):
    doc = Document()

    for word in words:
        p = doc.add_paragraph(word)
        run = p.runs[0]
        
        run.font.size = Pt(130)
        run.font.name = "Gulzar"
        run.element.rPr.rFonts.set(qn('w:eastAsia'), "Gulzar")
        
        p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
        p.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(78)
        
        doc.add_page_break()

    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path), exist_ok=True)
    doc.save(output_path)
    print(f"Saved Word document to {output_path}")

# Example usage
words = ["کلجقم", "کلجقم", "کلجقم"]
output_path = "output.docx"
create_word_document(words, output_path)


Despite setting p.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(78), the spacing is not being consistently applied to each word. How can I ensure that the same spacing before each paragraph is applied correctly?
Below I have attached images of the first two pages of the document. Both words are the same and should appear the same on different pages, but they do not:
Page 1 image
Page 2 image
How can I fix this issue to ensure consistent formatting across all pages?

This is more of a Word usage question.  Can you do this in Word directly, without using Python?

I provided this as an example with 2 or 3 words. I need to write 1.1 million words in a Word document.

I'm trying to help you narrow down whether it is a code issue or a native Word issue.  If the spacing is right when you enter it in Word, then it should be possible when controlling it remotely.

Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. I feel like there’s an issue with Word, as I can’t even set the same formatting for each manually.

This is a native problem in Word. Space before paragraph spacing is not applied to any paragraphs other than the first page of a section. You do NOT want a separate section for each page. This can be handled using frames in Word. https://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#SpaceBefore Frames can be a part of a style definition.

Btw.: Many thanks for run.element.rPr.rFonts.set(qn('w:eastAsia'), "Gulzar"). This saves me a lot of low level code to create run fonts attributes other than w:ascii and w:hAnsi. Me not aware of this simple possibility to set BaseOxmlElement attributes.

Using current Microsoft Word versions, space-before formatting, by design, does not work following a page break or column break.
Aside the solutions of to use a frame as part of the style or to set compatibility option, "Suppress Space Before after a hard page or column break" or to use tables, another solution may be using ParagraphFormat.page_break_before.
If ParagraphFormat.page_break_before is set True, then the paragraph itself performs a page break. So do using that instead of doc.add_page_break().
Complete example which works for me:
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.oxml.ns import qn
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
import os

def create_word_document(words, output_path):
    doc = Document()

    for word in words:
        p = doc.add_paragraph(word)
        run = p.runs[0]
        
        run.font.size = Pt(130)
        run.font.name = "Gulzar"
        run.element.rPr.rFonts.set(qn('w:eastAsia'), "Gulzar")
        
        p.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.CENTER
        p.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(78)
        
        #doc.add_page_break()
        p.paragraph_format.page_break_before = True

    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path), exist_ok=True)
    doc.save(output_path)
    print(f"Saved Word document to {output_path}")

# Example usage
words = ["کلجقم", "کلجقم", "کلجقم"]
output_path = "./output.docx"
create_word_document(words, output_path)

